# Send Synchronouse Request in Xamarin for IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, synchronization

How to send the Synchronouse Request in Xamarin.

```
string url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=xamarin&rpp=10&include_entities=false&result_type=mixed";
            NSUrlRequest urlRequest = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl (new Uri (url));
            NSUrlResponse response = null;
            NSError error = null;
            NSData data = NSUrlConnection.SendSynchronousRequest (urlRequest,response,error);
            Console.WriteLine ("Error Data value {0}", data);
```

This what i have done.

Can any one advice
How to send synchronous request in Xamarin IOS ?
IS there any Synchronouse Request is there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend against synchronous requests but if you must, you can use WebClient or HttpClient async with blocking call.

HttpClient call from sync function:

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=xamarin&rpp=10&include_entities=false&result_type=mixed").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
        }
```

WebClient call:

```
        var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

        try
        {
            var str = webClient.DownloadString("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=xamarin&rpp=10&include_entities=false&result_type=mixed");

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
```

Comment: For me HttpClient is not showing.  I used WebClient is working fine.  Using mac OSX 10.9.4 Xamarin 5.2

Comment: since I am unable to block UI thread, so I am using synchronous call.

Comment: You should be able to resolve the HttpClient (type it in, right click, resolve). If not, add reference to System.Net.Http and it should become available.